# Pointers and Pointers to pointers in a singly linked list, help me understand in C++

Tags: c++, list, pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm still trying to understand pointers, drawing nodes and everything but I can't seem to understand some things.

For example here is a function that should delete nodes with even values from a list

```
void delete_even()
{
    
    node* ptr = head;
    while (ptr)
    {
        if (ptr->data % 2 == 0)
        {
            nod* aux = ptr;
            ptr = ptr->next;
            delete aux;
        }
        else
        {
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }

}
```

As I understand it the pointer named `ptr` points to head which is the first node in the linked list.
[1 What my logic looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9hLi.png)
So  `while ptr=!null` check if the data in the head is even. It's not it's 1 so `ptr = ptr->next;`
that means (Ok, so make `ptr` point to whatever `ptr`'s next elemt is pointing to) and that makes the pointer `ptr` point to the second node in the list, right?
[2 as such](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbCvx.png)

Now that `ptr` is pointing to the second node and the `data` element is even, make a new pointer named `aux` and make point to the same node `ptr` is currently pointing at!
Now make `ptr` point to the next node, that would be the 3rd node in the list and delete `aux` that contains the address of the second node;[3 like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmNVq.png)

Now that I look again it probably doesn't work because the link is broken between the first node and the 3rd node... right?

Some cool guy came and told me to use pointers to pointers as it's much easier. and helped me with this code:

```
void delete_even()
{
    node **p= &head;

    while (*p)
    {
        if ((*p)->data % 2 == 0)
        {
           node *nextptr=*p;

           *p=(*p)->next;
           delete nextptr;
        }
        else
        {
            p= &(*p)->next;
        }
    }
}
```

So as I understand it. `p` is pointing to the pointer named `head`  that is pointing to the first node.[4 like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3wOL.png).

`p` means look at the thing `p` is pointing at, in this case it should be the pointer `head`
`*p` means look at the thing `p` is pointing at, in this, the pointer `head` and then look again to the thing `head` is pointing at, so this should be the first node, right?

I think I got that right.

Now while `*p!=NULL` (while the first node is pointing at anything other than NULL)
Verify if the first's node `data` is even. It's not, it's 1. So make `p` (the `head` pointer) have the address of the second node.
[5 like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFPXL.png)
Now we see that the data is 2 and it's even so we make a pointer named `nextptr` and we make this pointer point to the same thing `*p` is pointing at, which is the second node, correct?
After that we look at the thing `*p` is pointing (the second node) and we make it move to the next node and we delete the `nextptr` pointer.
[6 last one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/635w0.png)

On paper it looks the same to me, maybe my drawings and understanding is not right. but I'm spend days trying to make sense to it and it just doesn't...
I mean the second code works fine but I just don't understand why when the logic seems the same as the first one. Anyone that knows how to explain better?

Comment: try deleting first node and see what happens... you need to update head when you delete the first node. normally you would keep a pointer to the prev node at all times, whenever you want to delete a node, use the prev ptr to set it to the node after ptr after which you can delete the current node.

Comment: *"Now while *p!=NULL (while the first node is pointing at anything other than NULL) "* - should be "while the pointer pointed to by `p` is non-null". The concept of "first node" really isn't relevant.

Answer (score 1):

> So make `p` (the `head` pointer) have the address of the second node.

There are two problems with this statement.

First, `p` is not the `head` pointer. Rather `p` *points to* the `head` pointer (at this point in the process). When `p` changes, `head` is left unchanged. (On the other hand, if **`*p`** were to change, that would affect `head`.)

Second, the new value is not the address of the second node (`(*p)->next`). Rather, it is the address of the `next` pointer in the first node (`&(*p)->next`). Note the `&`.

So image five should look like the following:

```
head    p 
  |     |
  V     |
--------+----   ------------   ------------   ------------
|       V   |   |          |   |          |   |          |
|    -------|   |   -------|   |   -------|   |   -------|
| 1  | next-+-->| 2 | next-+-->| 3 | next-+-->| 4 | NULL |
|    -------|   |   -------|   |   -------|   |   -------|
-------------   ------------   ------------   ------------
```

See if you can take it from here. (You were doing well until this step, so I think you can.) In case you—or someone else—gets stuck or just wants to check what image six should be, here is the situation just before deleting node 2:

> ```
> head    p
>   |     |
>   V     |
> --------+----                  ------------   ------------
> |       V   |                  |          |   |          |
> |    -------|                  |   -------|   |   -------|
> | 1  | next-+----------------->| 3 | next-+-->| 4 | NULL |
> |    -------|   ------------   |   -------|   |   -------|
> -------------   |          |   ------------   ------------
>                 |   -------|     ^
>      nextptr--->| 2 | next-+-----|
>                 |   -------|
>                 ------------
> ```

It might also be helpful to check your result against another iteration of the loop. So here is what would be image seven:

> ```
> head                                  p
>   |                                   |
>   V                                   |
> -------------                  -------+----   ------------
> |           |                  |      V   |   |          |
> |    -------|                  |   -------|   |   -------|
> | 1  | next-+----------------->| 3 | next-+-->| 4 | NULL |
> |    -------|                  |   -------|   |   -------|
> -------------                  ------------   ------------
> ```

*Commentary: a trailing pointer can be easier to understand than this pointer-to-pointer approach.*

Answer (score 0):

Both implementations are actually wrong. There are several issues with them.

1. There is an edge case that is not being taken care of. It is when the first element, the one pointed by `head` is deleted - the head pointer needs to be updated with the next value. And obviously, this logic needs to be recursive such that it works with the new head after the previous head was deleted as well.
2. There is also logic missing to link up the last pointer over the current pointer. For that you need to maintain a `last` pointer and update the `last->next` pointer with `ptr->next` to keep the list connected. If the `last` pointer is null, you know that `head` needs to be updated.
3. There is also the mixing of too many decisions being made at the same time, which makes the algorithm unnecessarily complex. I like the idiom where the algorithm saves the next pointer before any action be taken. This frees up mental logic to think about what needs to be actually done with the data rather than trying to juggle the two streams at the same time in your head.
4. A minor rhetorical fix while checking for the validity of the pointer. Better check against `nullptr` than assuming that the null pointer is zero.

I would rewrite it like this:

```cpp
void delete_even()
{
    // Initialize the iterator
    node* ptr = head;
    node* last = nullptr;

    // loop while the current pointer is not null
    while (ptr!=nullptr)
    {
        // Save the pointer to next node 
        node* next = ptr->next;

        // If the data is even, delete and reconnect everything
        if (ptr->data % 2 == 0) {

            // Delete the data
            delete ptr;

            // Reconnect the previous pointer so the list is intact
            // This is the head node
            if ( last==nullptr ) head = next;
            // There is a previous valid node
            else last->next = next;
        } else {
           // Update last to the last valid node
           last = ptr;
        }

        // Proceed to the next node
        ptr = next;
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the first issue is just a special case of the second. Looks odd to say that one issue is that the last pointer is not updated, and also call out an edge case of that issue (when the last pointer is `head`) as its own issue.

Comment: *"Better check against `nullptr` than assuming that the null pointer is zero."* -- you are referring to `while (ptr)`? That assumes that the null pointer is `false`, not that it is zero. Assuming that a null pointer converts to `false` is legitimate; see [Boolean conversions @ cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Boolean_conversions): *"the null pointer and the null pointer-to-member values become `false`"* (Some style guides prefer `!=nullptr`, though.)